# Interrupted Time Series Poission garmaFit not working

Tags: time-series, regression, poisson, autocorrelation

I am trying to fit my Poission time series model into garmaFit (package gamlss) but my parameters are not working.

```
model6.0 <-garmaFit(aces ~ time+ smokban + offset(log(stdpop)), data=data, order=c(0,0),phi.start =11 ,theta.start = 11, family=PO)
```

This runs the model but does not adjust it from the coefficients I can generate from

```
model1 <- glm(aces ~ offset(log(stdpop)) + smokban + time, family=poisson, data)
```

I even tried using a known method to control for autocorrelation in a ols model (from a different dataset) and it did not adjust the coefficients from the original mode.

Cannot find elsewhere how to adjust p/q values in the phi.start and theta.start parameters

Any help would be appreciated